# Bibtex and Miktex: A bibliography program (empty) bbl file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, miktex

There are quite few posts with the same problem and I think I tried all of them, and couldn't solve the issue.

I am using a thesis template and Texmaker on Ubuntu, so, I guess following lines related to reference.

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibbase}
```

I have an empty `planinnat.bst`,

and this is my .bib file

```
@INPROCEEDINGS {author:06,
 title    = {Some publication title},
 author   = {First Author and Second Author},
 crossref = {conference:06},
 pages    = {330—331},
}
@PROCEEDINGS {conference:06,
 editor    = {First Editor and Second Editor},
 title     = {Proceedings of the Xth Conference on XYZ},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the Xth Conference on XYZ},
 year      = {2006},
 month     = oct,
}
```

and by running `bibtex` on the .aux file a `.blg` file is generated and it looks like this

```
This is 8-bit Big BibTeX version 0.99c Implementation:  C for Unix Release version: 3.71 (31 May 2005)

The 8-bit codepage and sorting file: 88591lat.csf The top-level auxiliary file: master2010.aux The style file: plainnat.bst

Here's how much of BibTeX's memory you used:  Cites:                 4 out of 750  Fields:                0 out of 17250  Hash table:         4998 out of 5000  Strings:              89 out of 4000  String pool:   590 out of 65530  Wizard functions:      0 out of 3000
```

So, apparently bibtex found 4 citations, and I expect to have a `.bbl` file as well, but it's empty.

EDIT : I found a [plainnat.bst from here](https://cdcsp.univ-lyon1.fr/parcfd/plainnat.bst), and now, .bbl is not empty anymore,but its not what I expect !

Its just like this

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{{\tt #1}}\fi

\bibitem[aut()]{author:06}


\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "I have an empty plainnat.bst"? Has the _style file_ no contents?

Comment: no content at all !, could it be predefined in latex ?

Comment: An empty `plainnat.bst` file is unusual. Double check the file; run in a terminal `kpsewhich plainnat.bst`
to find the location of the file in your system and check the contents of that file. If, for some reason, it was accidentally deleted or overwritten, you can find the file in CTAN: [plainnat.bst](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst)

Comment: I recommend to use the package `biblatex`. It is more comfortably and I am sure you will find more person who are able to work with `biblatex` than any bst-file.

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer (so, if you want to, you can up-vote it and accept it)

Comment: I had the exact same problem... I think it's because **Texmaker can't find the bibliography style file**. The only style that works for me by default is 'plain'! It would be nice if Texmaker was at least able to complain that the style file was missing... or maybe it's MikTeX's responsibility?

Comment: @H.Arponen: Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background. Please also add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty `plainnat.bst` file is unusual. Double check the file; run in a terminal

```
kpsewhich plainnat.bst
```

to find the location of the file in your system and check the contents of that file. If, for some reason, it was accidentally deleted or overwritten, you can find the file in CTAN: [plainnat.bst](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst)